# print the output form pspdfkit

Tags: excel, pspdfkit

everyone,today I  use "pspdfkit" to convert a excel file to pdf,but my output only have one page,the pdf file can be readed  in normal way,but if i want to print it(in office) , the data will squeezed together,is there any solution?

[image]
*this is my outcoming*

[image]
*if i want to print the file,the data will be too small to read.Also there's only one page in the result*

`instructions = { 'parts': [ { 'file': 'document' } ] }`
*this is my instructions  code*

**I wish the file can be split in many pages, should I change the code in instructions?**
thanks everyone for provideing solution.

Comment: I can not find a golang package for pspdfkit. Is the `go` tag added by accident? I will remove the `go` tag for now. If I'm wrong, please provide more detail. Thank you!